# Randon value from 0 to 60 for jmeter http request

Tags: jmeter

I want to pass 0 to 60 random value each time for my http request in jmeter. I'm automating API request through Jmeter.

I have tried `${__RandomString(10,,randomID)}` but request failed.

If anyone quickly help that would greatly helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here try, this..

```
${__Random(0,60,randomID)}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) which generates a number within the given range.

```
${__Random(0,60,randomID)}
```

With [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) you can only generate 2-digits number but the range will not be guaranteed and it will be between 00 and 99

```
${__RandomString(2,0123456789,randomID)}
```

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)